# Running django app on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run existing django project on google app engine using this [tutorial](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#zip-packages)

After copying the files I run manage.py runserver and I get the following error:

> ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot
>   resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named
>   RequireDebugFalse

Is there a problem with Django version? I use 1.3.7 but I don't know which one is used in this tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're following that tutorial, you have to use django-nonrel.

If you're not using django-nonrel, then you don't need to follow that tutorial.  You would follow a typical django tutorial, but you must use CloudSQL instead of the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

It's about your Django version. `RequireDebugFals`e is new in Django 1.4 ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse)).